# One of two properties is required from the data model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, asp.net-mvc-4

Let's say I have a `Person` class with `FirstName` and `LastName`. I want that the user must enter at least one of the two values in the UI but he may not have to enter each of them.

If I place the `Required` attribute / data annotation on each of them, that makes both of them required.

How do I make a server side validation (with client side validation, too) for this rule?

Comment: I do not know asp.net but if that work as doctrine in php, you should have an  event for prepersist datas on the database. You should create a condition on that event that throw an error if both values are null ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could use a custom attribute for this. In short, the custom attribute will retrieve both values and then ensure at least one has a value. See [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs2010trainingcourse_aspnetmvccustomvalidation_topic2) for more information. Here is an example (untested code):

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple =false, Inherited = false)]
  public class ValidatePersonName: ValidationAttribute
  {
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
      string FirstName = (string)validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty("FirstName").GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);

      string LastName = (string)validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty("LastName").GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);

  //check at least one has a value
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(FirstName) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(LastName))
        return new ValidationResult("At least one is required!!");

      return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
  }
```

Usage:

```
class Person{

 [ValidatePersonName]
 FirstName{get;set;}

 LastName{get;set;}
}
```